# Problems with geometry_msgs::PoseStamped

Tags: ros, geometry-msgs, message, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am try to write a tool that uses geometry_msgs::PoseStamped.
Unfortunately I always get the error

```
src/systemplatform.cpp.o: In function `feedbackLoop(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':  .../systemplatform.cpp:44: undefined reference to `Tool::getPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, double*)' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error appears in Source File: systemplatform.c with the call of `tool.getPose(msgPose, posetypeRNum);`
I don't find the error, but can imagine that is related to the use or call of msgPose which should be `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped rosTopicMsg;`
It would be really nice if you could help me.
I have added the code as following:

Thanks a lot in Advance!!!

//=============================================================================

//Header File:  systemplatform.c

```
/* Required Headers */
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "std_msgs/Empty.h"
#include "std_srvs/Empty.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include "tf/tf.h"
#include "tf/transform_broadcaster.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include "tool.h"
```

//=============================================================================

//Source File:  systemplatform.c

```
#include "systemplatform.h"

/*Tool-class-pointers*/
Tool toolPtr;

/*Subscriber initialization*/
ros::Subscriber toolSubscriber;


void feedbackLoop(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& msgPose)
{
    typeRNum posetypeRNum [5]={0,0,0,0,0};
    tool.getPose(msgPose, posetypeRNum);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "tool");
    ros::NodeHandle ntool;  //For receiving OptitrackData

    toolSubscriber = ntool.subscribe("tooltopic", 10, feedbackLoop);
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

//=============================================================================

//Header File: tool.h

```
/* Required Headers */
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "tf/tf.h"
#include "tf/transform_broadcaster.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"

class Tool
{
  public:

  void getPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped rosTopicMsg, double* posetypeRNum);
};
#endif
```

//=============================================================================

//Source File: tool.cpp

```
#include "tool.h"
void Toll::getPose(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped rosTopicMsg, double* array)
{
...
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206999/problems-with-geometry_msgs::posestamped/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The linker error message is pretty clear: It tells that the function which you are calling in `feedbackLoop()`, `Tool::getPose(...)`, is declared in a header file, but its implementation is not defined.

In tool.cpp you have a typo: It says `Toll::getPose` instead of `Tool::getPose`. I wonder why you are getting a linker error, though, as this should already cause an error during compilation because a `Toll`class it not declared anywhere. In your CMakeLists.txt, did you forget to add tool.cpp as a source file in the add_executable() / add_library() call?

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0